# Create neo4j container with apoc using testcontainers library

Tags: neo4j, testcontainers, neo4j-apoc

I'm using Testcontainers library version 10.7.1 with nodeJS.
I need to create neo4j container with Apoc.
I wrote this code:

```
const container = await new Neo4jContainer()
.withExposedPorts(7687)
.withUser('neo4j')
.withPassword('password')
.withApoc()
.start();
```

and when running it I get this error:
Error: Log stream ended and message "Started." was not received

When removing the `.withApoc()` things works as expected.
How can I make it work with Apoc?

Comment: Try increasing the startupTimeout. .withStartupTimeout(120_000)